# jQuery Validate not removing valid label on clearing contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I love the `jQuery.validate.js` plugin, but whilst implementing it on a new form I'm working on, I can't get the `valid` `class` and `label` to be removed from an `input` element when it's contents are removed.

I have `onkeyup` set to `false`, a `success` function to add a `valid` class to the error label and the field is `required`:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#test').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: 'Please enter a first name'
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass('valid').text('Yey!');
        },
        onkeyup: false
    });
});
</script>

<form id="test">
    <label>Name<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /></label>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kw8Lm/

The following senario is what I'd like to change:

1. User types in a value into the field
2. 'Yey' label is displayed next to the field
3. User goes back and clears out the field
4. 'Yey' label is still displayed

I'd like step 4 to be changed so that it's no longer shown - either the error message of `Field required` should be shown or no error at all would also be fine (as there's nothing in it).

Weirdly I can get the thing to work if `onkeyup` is set to `true` but I just don't want that functionality of error checking whilst typing, bit much for the user I think.

Any help is much appreciated, I can't find any solution to this in other posts - sorry if I missed something.

Cheers!

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not constructed properly.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/KLG9k/

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, I used the `errorPlacement` option, which is fired every time an error message needs to be placed.  It over-rides your "Yay!" message whenever the error message needs to come back.

(Please note the how the code is placed inside this jsFiddle.)

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/vwH2x/**

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: 'Please enter a first name'
        },
        success: function (label) {
            label.addClass('valid').text('Yey!');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        onkeyup: false
    });
});
```

---

> "Weirdly I can get the thing to work if onkeyup is set to true"

**Something worth noting:**

The `onkeyup` is one of the default options that is either set to `false` or left out entirely.  Setting it to `true` is not valid for this plugin.  There is a function behind this `onkeyup` option and setting it to `false` is a valid method of disabling this function.  However, setting it to `true` should never be done.  Leaving out the `onkeyup` option simply allows the default `onkeyup` behavior to occur.